# Java Swing - Dynamically create JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to create several JTextFields that I can then get the user data from once they hit a submit button. I am using the code below to dynamically create labels for the text fields and was planning on creating the text fields in a similar way, but I realized that if I do that the fields won't have variable names and I won't be able to extract the data. Is there a way to dynamically assign variable names or otherwise retrieve the data from the text fields if I create them in a way similar to what's shown below?

```
    int autoX = 0;
    int autoY = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< units.numOfUnits(); i++ ){
        c.gridx = (autoX % 5);
        c.gridy = autoY;
        if((autoX % 5) == 4){
            autoY++;
        }
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel(units.getUnit(i)),c);
        autoX++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the text fields you create. Like this:

```
List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
int autoX = 0;
int autoY = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< units.numOfUnits(); i++ ){
    c.gridx = (autoX % 5);
    c.gridy = autoY;
    if((autoX % 5) == 4){
        autoY++;
    }
    mainPanel.add(new JLabel(units.getUnit(i)),c);
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    mainPanel.add(textField);
    textFields.add(textField);
    autoX++;
}
```

Then you can refer to a specific text field with:

```
textFields.get(0).getText();
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up making the List a private variable of the class the code is in to make it accessible by other methods but I didn't state it was in a class.